# How can processing in a Promise be triggered before it is needed to be resolved, like a java Future?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js

I have a integration test written in Mocha that needs to register a listener before other things take place, otherwise I end up with a race condition.

Basically, I am sending a post to some HTTP server, then expecting a callback from a Kafka messaging service with some message I need to check the value of. (The post to the http server is putting the message on kafka).

My initial cut at this ends in a race condition.

```
var request = require("supertest-as-promised");
var Promise = require("bluebird");

beforeEach() { //set up kafka connection and kafkaConsumer ... }
describe('send-status', function statusSend() {
    it("sends a post to the server and gets a message on kafka", function (done) {
           request('http://myserver:8080')
                    .post('/myendpoint')
                    .type('json')
                    .send(stuff)
                    .expect(200)
            })
            .then(function () {
                //todo:  antipattern - can be replaced with a custom promisfier.
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    kafkaConsumer.on('message', function (message) {
                            resolve(message)
                        })
                        //and reject cases
                });
            })
            .then(function (message) {
                //check message
                done()
             })
            .catch() ...
```

The problem is of course the kafka message can get fired right after the post but right before the 2nd promise can register the `kafkaConsumer.on('message')` listener.

So I need to register the `kafkaConsumer.on('message')` before I start the post request promise in the chain.

This is where my knowledge of node and promises falls apart.  If this were Java, I'd create a Callable that starts the listener (and maybe have a latch wait until it got started before my post), throw that on an executor and use that future later - the value would either be already there or the Future would wait for it.

With promises, I don't understand how to start the `kafkaConsumer.on('message')` before the then() gets called in the chain.

I tried something like this, but it was ugly and still can result in a race condition:

```
function foo(message) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(message);
    });
}
describe(...)
    it("sends post to ...", function(done) {
        var onMessagePromise;
        kafkaConsumer.on('message', function (message) {
            onMessagePromise = foo(message)
        });

        request()
        .then(function () {
            return onMessagePromise;
        })
        .then ...
```

One other idea I had was to listen for the messages before doing the request, assigning it to a variable and then having the promise resolve on that variable...  but that won't work if the message comes after the promise is returned and kind defeats the point.   Everything I can think of results in a race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I need to register the `kafkaConsumer.on('message')` before I start the post request promise in the chain.

You can do that, and from your explanation it sounds pretty similar to how it would be solved in Java (although I don't know a lot about Java, so I'm sure that will be *some* differences):

```
var kafkaPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  kafkaConsumer.on('message', function (message) {
    resolve(message);
  })
  //and reject cases
});

request('http://myserver:8080')
        .post('/myendpoint')
        .type('json')
        .send(stuff)
        .expect(200)
        .then(function() {
          return kafkaPromise;
        })
        .then(...)
        .catch(...);
```

If `kafkaPromise` is resolved, its value will be used; if it's still pending, the chain will wait until it gets resolved (or rejected) before continuing.